# Posting a nested Bean to Spring MVC RequestMethod with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have two POJOs defined of which one is the member of the other

```
public class Command {

    private String cmd;
    private String environment;

    public String getCmd() {
        return cmd;
    }

    public void setCmd(String cmd) {
        this.cmd = cmd;
    }

    public String getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(String environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}

public class Task {

    private String type;
    private Command command;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Command getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    public void setCommand(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to post an instances of an Task object including a Command object from a webpage using the jQuery post method:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Task</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="addTask" id="addTask">addTask</a>
<div id="tasklist"></div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/2.1/jquery-min.js" />"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#addTask").click( function() {

        var command = {
            cmd: 'do',
            environment: 'sh'
        };
        var data = {
            type: 'once',
            command: command
        };
        $.post("addTask", data)
                  .done(function (data) {
                      $("#tasklist").empty().append(content);
                  })
                  .fail(function (data) {
                      $("#messages").empty().apppend(data);
                  });
        return false;
      });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working for the pure Task bean with no nested `Command` member is included or if I replace `Command` member by a native Javascript object e.G. a Date which then is perfectly mapped to a `java.util.Date` object.

I do process the POST-request using Spring MVC:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addTask", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getTask(){
        return  new ModelAndView("task");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addTask(@ModelAttribute Task task) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("task");
        // do something with task
        return mv;
    }
}
```

However, it results in the error message below and I can't find a solution

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception   [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'command[cmd]' of bean 
class [Task]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'command[cmd]' 
is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [do]] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'command[cmd]' 
of bean class [Task]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'command[cmd]' 
    is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [do]
```

The above code is a simplified but verified example of my problem. The reason for not including all information in one POJO is, that for certain task types the `command` member may be null.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: As far as I remember at the moment not really, no. I put my trials and error to a public repository at the timeover at github https://github.com/cyc1ingsir/SpringMVCParameters you might have a look at it. I tried to keep it as simple as possible in order to keep the focus on the problem. HTH Iwould de glad to hear about your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Running your example shows that the server receives the following data:

```
type:once
command[cmd]:do
command[environment]:sh
```

The [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans) shows the following syntax for bean conversion:

```
account[COMPANYNAME] : Indicates the value of the map entry indexed by the key COMPANYNAME of the Map property account
```

This means that spring is expecting Task.command to be a Map.
You should therefore either find a way to post the nested values as

```
command.cmd: do
command.environment: sh
```

or change the java model to something like

```
public class Task {

    private String type;
    private Map<String, String> command;
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful hint but so far I've not been able to send the object formatted/serialized this way using JS/jquery. In the project I had this problem initially, I worked around it by splitting the objects in smaller one combining them in a larger from which I serialize using `$("form").serialize()` prior to submitting.  
To get the example working, the main question now would be: How to post the object using JS/JQuery?  
Having searched a bit further, I wonder if `@ModelAttribute` - annotation is being rightly used in my example, though. But that's another issue.